# Highcharts not displaying daily data for column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So I have a stacked column chart, type of datetime, with minTickInterval of one day. In some cases for my data, my chart displays fine, with each stack in its own day, but for other cases, the column seem to overlap and instead Highchart does a "week of ...". I have no idea what could be wrong in the config. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLvNW/)

I already tried this with no luck

```
dataGrouping: {
 enabled: false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing I notice is that your data is not for the same timestamp. This means that the data will not stack as their x-values are different. If you want all data to for a given date to be stacked then you have to give them the same date (and time). The `dataGrouping` only applies to HighStock. Your `toolTip` text can be formatted.

Answer (score 1):

The cahrt is displayed correctl,y becasue you have stacked for the same x value, for for different, points are neighbours.

Answer (score 0):

For each series data, I had to use

```
pointRange: 86400000 // equal to one day
```

The first answer here solved it.

[Highcharts columnchart: How to seperate overlapping columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707612/highcharts-columnchart-how-to-seperate-overlapping-columns)